# Failure to publish coverage report and nunit test result on SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Executed the vstest for the code coverage & converted into an .xml file from the .coverage file ext. 
Also have the .XML result/output file for the nunit test.

Added the below entries in the sonar properties file:

```
sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=.\Testing\TestResult.xml
sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=.\Coverage\CoverageResults.xml
```

No data seen in the SonarQube interface.

I see some log entries like

> 23:08:39.426 INFO - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report
>   e:\jenkins\workspace\Sonar.\Coverage\CodeCoverageResults.xml
>   23:08:39.451 DEBUG - Code coverage will not be imported for the
>   following file outside of SonarQube:...

Comment: You want to be a little more expansive about what _does_ happen?

Comment: I see some log entries like 23:08:39.426 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report e:\jenkins\workspace\Sonar\.\Coverage\CodeCoverageResults.xml
23:08:39.451 DEBUG - Code coverage will not be imported for the following file outside of SonarQube:

Answer (score 0):

At a guess - because you don't give a whole lot to go on here - the sources under analysis don't overlap with the sources under test.

Comment: all my search on this error, speaks of that but i cannot really understand. Can you give an example or some docs that i can refer